# Firebase notification console equivalent in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have the following code to send push notification in my node server[image]

this works fine when the app is in foreground or in background. However this do not work when the app is killed.

Using firebase notification console, the push is received even when the app is killed

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the same behavior of firebase console, we should set the priority to 10, so it will awaken the app